# Joint accumulation of addition and multiplication

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4])
```

and I want to do the following calculation:

```
out = 0
for e in a:
    out *= 3
    out += e
```

With `out` as the output (`4582` for the given example), is there a nice way to vectorize this? I think `einsum` can be used, but I couldn't figure how to write it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4])
powers = np.multiply.accumulate(np.repeat(3, len(a) - 1))
res = np.sum(powers[::-1] * a[:-1]) + a[-1]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
4582
```

If you expand the loop, you'll notice that you are multiplying each value of `a` by a power of 3 and then summing the result.

Comment: Nice, I am not sure if this correct, but this seems to also give the output ```4582```: ```(3**np.arange(len(a))[::-1] * a).sum()```, It is slightly more concise.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would use `reduce`:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x * 3 + y, a)
```

Comment: This is a nice way to express the calculation compactly, but does not seem to offer any performance gains over the direct solution.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem well, *nice*  does not necessarily mean *fast* - I answered the question literally. The question does not mention enormous lists to process, but a nice way without using loops...

Comment: I agree. It is just that usually questions about numpy vectorization are associated with performance.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem don't get me wrong - I see your point and I would be interested to see how you would approach it as well

Comment: I find that wrapping the direct solution in `@numba.jit` gains a speedup of up to 40x until integer overflow becomes an issue. After that point, it really depends on what OP intends to do.

Comment: Actually the question ask about vectorization, this is not a vectorize approach